# Create shared Google Drive document owned by web service

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm new to the Google APIs, and would like to write a small service class for my web application that:

- creates blank Google document without user assistance
- assigns a generated title
- returns a URL that can be provided to multiple people to edit this document

This document mst be editable via a sharing link. Ideally it is owned/managed as part of the web service's Drive storage.

Code is welcome if it's easier than explaining, but I'm really asking for help understanding Google's service offering.

- Can I fully authenticate using only credentials specific to my app? (e.g. call the Drive API without prompting an interloper/observer/user to
  authenticate.)
- Once authenticated, can I create documents local to my
  API?
- Whose quota are the created documents consuming, the person that created the API key?
- Can I share
  these created documents with others?
- Will I be able to manage a list of
  these created file URLs from a standard Google web UI?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify what it is that you are asking. You want to be able to embed a google doc on your website A couple things that can happen here.

First, you will need to create a google doc, lets say a spreadsheet. Within that spreadsheet you will:
click File > Publish to the Web.
From here a new window will be brought up. Click Embed and Published content and settings and click the publish button. Ensure the Automatically republish when changes are made checkbox. (this will allow for your website to be automatically updated anytime that doc is changed.

Take the embedded link that is generated and plop it in your webpage and it will be live.

Now you can share the page via Google Docs and anyone that has that link can make changes to that spreadsheet. As soon as a change is made, it will update on your website with the next refresh.

Hope this is all clear, let me know if there is anything unclear.
Cheers

Comment: No, sorry it wasn't clearer. The application creates the document without user assistance, as part of a workflow. Whether or not the document is displayed within my application, is not important to me at this time.